# Как получить доступ к DIV внутри DIV?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

Есть такой код html:

```
<div class="fullnews">
   <div class="fullnews-header"><a href="#">Some Text</a></div><br />
   <div class="fullnews-header">Post Title</div>
</div>
```

Надо запарсить 2-й блок *fullnews-header*, пропустив первый *fullnews-header*, в котором лежат ссылки. Как это сделать? Laravel / PHP. Готовый парсер есть уже, только заходит в первый блок *fullnews-header*...

Comment: через `css` достучаться можно вот так: `.fullnews .fullnews-header:nth-of-type(2)` - может поможет и спарсить

Comment: Попробовал:
1 - .fullnews .fullnews-header:nth-of-type(2) = ErrorException... ( оно пропускает и берет весь блок  .fullnews и там очень много текста. Експешен на то что текста много. Тобишь - не рабоатет так.
2 - .fullnews-header:nth-of-type(2) = ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Array to string conversion.
Я немогу лезть в другие файлы сайта, разве что просить владельца менять етот блок =/

Comment: > Готовый парсер есть уже, только заходит в первый блок fullnews-header...

Покажите то, что у вас есть, так будет проще.

Comment: Мне надо перепрыгнуть через первый блок. Как ето сделать Laravel 4 / PhP 5.4

Answer (score 1):

В Laravel, кажется, есть встроенные инструменты из компонентов Symfony, но стандартными средствами это можно сделать так:

```
$html = '<div class="fullnews">
   <div class="fullnews-header"><a href="#">Some Text</a></div><br />
   <div class="fullnews-header">Post Title</div>
</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$container = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' fullnews ')]")[0];

$node = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' fullnews-header ')]", $container)[1];

var_dump($node->textContent);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a895ca8f4929f3c69f7dacbb17530a159f2e077b

Comment: Работает на ура, только с РнР 5.6.1+, Помогите пожалуйста интегрировать ето в  Laravel? PhP 5.4 + Laravel 4 .

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array

Comment: Для устаревших версий php нужно просто вынести выбор по индексу массива в отдельный шаг:

$containerNodes = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' fullnews ')]");
$container = $containerNodes[0];

Comment: Спасибо, помоголо.